# TestRail: Bulk attachments upload via API

Tags: testing, testrail

I want to upload test results with the screenshots via API. Is there any way to do that? So far, I've been uploading only test results without attachments using this endpoint [add_results_for_cases](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/results#addresultsforcases).
Please advise what is the best way to upload attachments along with the test results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `add_attachment_to_result` endpoint to add an attachment to the result based on the result id - Please check out this [documentation](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/attachments#addattachmenttoresult).